# How to promote questions/get answers?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*I wasn't sure if this is the right place to ask this question. So feel free to delete it if not appropriate, sorry about that.*

Anyway my question is, is there any way to get answers to unanswered questions that are lost in the website. Like maybe some way to promote the question or send it to people experienced in that area so we can get answers quicker.

Thank you very much.

Update:
Updating helps to promote the question but I wish that was the same for comments too. Since currently comments are only notified to the person who wrote the original answer and doesn't promote the question on the homepage.

Also, I don't think people up-voting a question has any effect on its visibility?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175134/how-to-promote-questions/get-answers?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-16**:
Comments notify everyone that somehow interacted with the question besides just viewing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can update a question, so it will be again on the first side and no longer "lost".
But you should add more information with the update or rephrase the question. There is a reason why the question remains unanswered.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2014-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-06-26**:
That works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Updating the question puts it on top of the question list, but that's only helpful if the right person sees it before it gets bumped down and off the front page again.

I just noticed a feature over on the Gazebo answers site that might be useful to add to this site.
http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

At the bottom of every unanswered question is a bold prompt asking the viewer if they know someone who might know the answer and it has a mailto: link that you can click on which will seed your email client with the link.  That might help promotion of unanswered questions.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-03**:
That's a good point !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience there are two reasons for questions not being answered.

1. The question is not done very well, e.g. missing basic information, formatting, structure, answer is in docs/tutorials/google, etc.
   The [guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) help and in this case an update is a good idea. Also when new information was discovered.
2. No one that has seen the question knows an answer. To trigger relevant people choose a valid title and use correct tags. Ideally reuse tags that are already in use as some people might selectively only look at tags they care about.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3